# ConcurrentHashMap read, write and clear()

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Suppose there are 3 reading threads and 1 writing thread. 
The writing thread calls map.clear(). What exception or effect will be caused by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clear` method will *clear* the whole map, i.e. deleting all entries.

In view of concurrency, for **reading** actions, nothing changes. They will just read the value the map has at the point of time they access it. However for other threads that use **writing** actions the `ConcurrentHashMap` automatically waits for the `clear` operation to finish such that you do not experience such *strange effects* that come with non synchronized concurrency.

---

Just carefully read through the official documentation, it explains all effects: [ConcurrentHashMap Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: "In view of concurrency the other threads will automatically wait for the clear operation to finish and then reading on the cleared map." According to the Javadoc of `ConcurrentHashMap` this statement is false. Readers do not wait on writers, but they return the most current state, which they can access.

Comment: You are **correct**, it only holds for writing actions which also makes sense and exactly that is the **main advantage** to a class that would just synchronize all actions: **Reading** actions can be taken fast, without synchronization overhead and only **writing** actions have that overhead. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It will clear the map, just as its name suggests.